# Google sheets formula based upon a unique identifier and a date match (in between two dates)

Tags: google-sheets, filter, match

I have two spreadsheets:

Spreadsheet 1:
An ID #,
A date

Spreadsheet 2 range rows:
ID#,
Start date,
End Date,
Pay

I need to match an ID #, match that the date is between two dates (start and end date) and have the result be the pay listed on spreadsheet 2 when K is listing pay.

This is causing an error:

```
=filter('Spreadsheet 2'!K:K,'Spreadsheet 2'!A:A=D3,'Spreadsheet 2'!E:E=<F3,'Spreadsheet 2'!F:F=>F3)
```

Comment: Which is the error shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `>=` and `<=` instead of `=>` and `=<`

```cpp
=FILTER('Spreadsheet 2'!K:K,'Spreadsheet 2'!A:A=D3,'Spreadsheet 2'!E:E<=F3,'Spreadsheet 2'!F:F>=F3)
```